# SELECT query where LIMIT is a distinct count of repeating key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with selecting specific amount of data. The problem is that one of the keys have the same repeated value.

```
--------------------
| id | name | key |
--------------------
| 1  | alfa |  a  |
| 2  | alfa |  b  |
| 3  | alfa |  c  |
| 4  | beal |  a  |
| 5  | beal |  b  |
| 6  | gala |  c  |
| 7  | gala |  d  |
| 8  | delt |  a  |
| 9  | ceta |  a  |
--------------------
```

In this situation I want to select three individual names. For example I want to limit distinct name to 3 positions to get this result:

**SAMPLE DUMP CODE:**

```
SELECT * in Table
WHERE `name` LIKE '%al%' 
LIMIT BY DISTINCT
 `name`, 3
```

---

```
------ RESULT ------
| 1  | alfa |  a  |
| 2  | alfa |  b  |
| 3  | alfa |  c  |
| 4  | beal |  a  |
| 5  | beal |  b  |
| 6  | gala |  c  |
| 7  | gala |  d  |
--------------------
```

I will be glad for help.

Comment: limit 3 based on what - first 3 by id , last 3 by id, lowest 3 by key per name?

Comment: Could be first by id

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The example based on the `RESULT` table: I have search field and I am looking for some world. I put `al` characters into the text field. As a search result I want to display all keys for the individual name and later work on each object.

Comment: @Dzeremix What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct name
  from mytable
  where `name` like '%al%' 
  order by name
  limit 3
) n
natural join mytable
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9HfJDwrRQN1ebDwE9A3N9L/0)

If you don't like NATURAL JOINs you can also use

```
select t.*
from (
  select distinct name
  from mytable
  where `name` like '%al%' 
  order by name
  limit 3
) n
join mytable t on t.name = n.name
```

If window functions are supported, you can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank):

```
with cte as (
  select *,
  dense_rank() over (order by name) as dr
  from mytable
  where `name` like '%al%'
)
  select id, name, `key`
  from cte
  where dr <= 3
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jqGfe25D4o1R1XjXzCAFq6/0)

I prefer the `LIMIT 3` subquery, since it can stop the index scan (depending on optimizer) after three distinct names are found.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 solution utilizing [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  dt.id, dt.name, dt.`key` 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) AS rn, 
    id, 
    name, 
    `key`
  FROM your_table_name 
  WHERE name LIKE '%al%'
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.rn <= 3 
ORDER BY dt.id
```

**Explanation:**

1. In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery), determine [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) within a partition (group) of specific name, ordered by `id` in ascending order. We will consider only names matching `%al%` condition.
2. Now, use the subquery result to `SELECT` only the rows having row number upto 3 (basically limiting to 3 rows per name).
3. By the way, `key` is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-K). You should consider renaming column to something else; otherwise you will need to use backticks around it.

**Result**

```
| id  | name | key |
| --- | ---- | --- |
| 1   | alfa | a   |
| 2   | alfa | b   |
| 3   | alfa | c   |
| 4   | beal | a   |
| 5   | beal | b   |
| 6   | gala | c   |
| 7   | gala | d   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZrD15s7uxE9rsMsVGfNHQ/0)